# How to count specific nodes in xml hierachy depends on condition in XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm writing a stylesheet in xsl (version 2.0) I want to know how could I count all nodes with a specific name although they're not siblings
for example in the following xml I want to count the numbers of Products from type -Milk but from all shops.
I want to know if there's a way to use the count function and not struggling with Recursion.
result should be 4 for this example

```
<Shops><Shop>
<Product>
    <Name>yogurt</Name>
    <type>Milk</type>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>cheese</Name>
    <type>Milk</type>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>bread</Name>
    <type>Bakery</type>
</Product> </Shop> <Shop>
<Product>
    <Name>yellow cheese</Name>
    <type>Milk</type>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>chocolate milk</Name>
    <type>Milk</type>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>bagel</Name>
    <type>Bakery</type>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>candy</Name>
    <type>Sweets</type>
</Product>  </Shop></Shops>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This avoids the slow "`//`" operator.

```
count(/Shops/Shop/Product[type = 'Milk'])
```

Comment: Thanks It works fine some how the count(//  doesn't give the expected result.
If I want to count preceding Products from all shops (siblings and cousins) what would be a correct way to count that?

Comment: `count(preceding::Product[type = 'Milk'])`. Have a look at http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/xslt/axis-sect.html and the XPath language spec http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath

Comment: P.S.: It is also not strictly required to accept an answer in 100% of your questions. But those answers that actually *solved your problem* should be accepted at some point.

Answer (score 2):

`count(//Product[type='Milk'])`

`//` finds all matching nodes anywhere in the document.